# Why is JavaScript styling working with all browsers except Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, php, css, internet-explorer, html5-video

I'm using video JS HTML5 player to play some videos and I want to add a visual representation of the chapters underneath the video player.

I'm basically grabbing how many chapters there are from the database and create that number of the divs with PHP.

```
 <div class="chapter-progress">
        <div class="chapter-breaker"></div>
        <? $tableName = 'sourceChapters';      
        $mysqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE recSourceId = "                          
       .$sourceVideo['recId']. " ORDER BY recOrdering ASC;";
        $sourceChapters = mysql_query($mysqlQuery); ?>
       <? $chapterBreakerNo = 0; ?>
       <? while($chapterBreakers = mysql_fetch_array($sourceChapters)){ ?>
          <div class="chapter-breaker-title" id="chapter-breaker-title<?=$chapterBreakerNo?>">    
          <p><?=$sourceChapters['recContent']?></p></div>
          <div class="chapter-breaker" id="chapter-breaker<?=$chapterBreakerNo?>"></div>
          <? $chapterBreakerNo++ ?>
          <? } ?>
          <div class="chapter-breaker-title" id="last-title"></div>
          <div class="chapter-breaker" style="float:right"</div>
  </div>
```

So there is chapter-breaker-title divs that are going to be styled to be the actual size of the chapters and there are chapter breaker which are just a line, 1% thick to split the chapters.

I then use a JavaScript onload function to style these divs.

```
 /* -----------------------------------------------function for styling the chapter progress bar ---------------------------------------*/

    function styleChapters(){
        //also run the chapter system on load
        chapterSys();
        // total video duration 
        var duration = myPlayer.duration();
        //find the time difference for the first chapter , this is just the chapter time 
        var timeDif = (<?=$chapterPlayOffsets[0]?>);
        // work out the percentage width for the div width
        var percentageMargin = ((timeDif/duration) * 100 -1);
        //get the first chapter breaker title and style the width 
        document.getElementById("chapter-breaker-title0").style.width = percentageMargin + "%";
        document.getElementById("chapter-breaker-title0").innerHTML="00";
       // for the rest of the chapters

       <? for($i=1;$i<count($chapterPlayOffsets);$i++) { ?>
        //total video duration
        var duration = myPlayer.duration();
        // find the difference between the chapter and the previous chapter
        var timeDif = (<?=$chapterPlayOffsets[$i]?>) - (<?=$chapterPlayOffsets[$i-1]?>);
        // get the percentage for div length minus 1% for the width of the chapter breakers
        var percentageMargin = ((timeDif/duration) * 100) -1;
        //style each of the divs width
        document.getElementById("chapter-breaker-title<?=$i?>").style.width = percentageMargin + "%";
                    //put the chapter title in 
        document.getElementById("chapter-breaker-title<?=$i?>").innerHTML="<?= $chapterTitles[$i-1] ?>";

      <? } ?>
      //put the last title in 
      <? $lastTitle = count($chapterPlayOffsets)-1 ?>
      document.getElementById("last-title").innerHTML="<?=$chapterTitles[$lastTitle] ?>"; 
    }
```

So this is what it should look like:

[image: The representation of the chapters]

The problem is that this works on all browsers apart from Internet Explorer.
It's as if the divs are not having their width styled at all.

So it looks like this:
[image: not good!]

If anyone can see or explain why this may not be working, it would be very helpful

```
.chapter-progress{
width:100%;
height:20px;
background: rgb(255,204,0)
  url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAGCAYAAADgzO9IAAAAP0lEQVQIHWWMAQoAIAgDR/QJ/Ub//04+w7ZICBwcOg5FZi5iBB82AGzixEglJrd4TVK5XUJpskSTEvpdFzX9AB2pGziSQcvAAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)
-50% 0 repeat; 
margin:auto;
float:left; 
}

.chapter-breaker{
height:100%;
width:1%;
background-color: rgb(0, 51, 153);
    float:left;
}

.chapter-breaker-title{
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

---

### HTML output :

```
div class="chapter-progress">
<div class="chapter-breaker"></div>
<div class="chapter-breaker-title" id="chapter-breaker-title0">
    00
</div>
<div class="chapter-breaker" id="chapter-breaker0"></div>
<div class="chapter-breaker-title" id="chapter-breaker-title1">
    01
</div>
<div class="chapter-breaker" id="chapter-breaker1"></div>
<div class="chapter-breaker-title" id="chapter-breaker-title2">
    02
</div>
<div class="chapter-breaker" id="chapter-breaker2"></div>
<div class="chapter-breaker-title" id="chapter-breaker-title3">
    03
</div>
<div class="chapter-breaker" id="chapter-breaker3"></div>
<div class="chapter-breaker-title" id="chapter-breaker-title4">
    04
</div>
<div class="chapter-breaker" id="chapter-breaker4"></div>
<div class="chapter-breaker-title" id="last-title">
    05
</div>
<div class="chapter-breaker" style="float: right;">
</div>
</div>
```

The ouput of the divs all seem fine to me but the javascript has not styled the width of the chapter-breaker-title divs

Comment: I think this is more CSS issue than JS. Post CSS.

Comment: Which version of IE?  Version 8 doesn't support HTML5.

Comment: @duffymo im using video js it has fallbacks for ie 8 .

Comment: @ivanIvanic ok ill post the css just give me a minute

Comment: off topic: please note that PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and obsolete. Please consider switching to one of the newer database APIs provided by PHP (either PDO or mysqli). However, for the purposes of this question, the PHP code is probably irrelevant; it would be better to show the actual HTML, as seen by the browser.

Comment: There's an error in the second to last line of your html. I don't know if that exists in your file as well. You don't close the tag for div.chapter-breaker

Comment: You should always look at the generated source code when debugging and not the serverside markup. Show us what is outputted to the browser with view source.

Comment: @rob-gordon no sorry i just missed the last div when pasting thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone gets a similar problem I had to put a time delay on my javascript to make it work , so before the page must not have loaded fully when my script was firing .